# Get column number by cell value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get the column number of a cell in the first row with a specific value.  The code I'm using isn't working for some reason.

```
Dim colNum As Integer
'sheetName is a String
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
colNum = column(.Match("ID", 1:1, 0))
```

It's telling me it's expecting a "list separator or )".  How do I make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim colNum As Integer
'sheetName is a String
colNum = WorksheetFunction.Match("ID", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetname).Range("1:1"), 0)
```

Comment: WORKING CORRECT WHAT I WANT ,,THANKS

Answer (score 4):

Note that if the match is not found it will return an error; try this to handle that.

```
Dim Result As Variant
If Not VBA.IsError(Application.Match(...)) Then
    Result = Application.Match(...)
End If
```

This tries the match and if there is an error on the function it will not assign a result.

[WorksheetFunction.Match Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx)